# Non-constructible conditions on the fibers that lift from the generic point to a non-empty open

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a flat morphism of schemes, with an irreducible locally Noetherian target. Call a condition on the fibers of $f$ "good" if the condition holds at the generic point of $Y$ iff it holds on a non-empty open set. What are some geometrically interesting examples of non-constructible "good" conditions on the fibers?

Comment: What do you mean by constructible?

Comment: @AviSteiner the locus where this condition holds is a constructible subset of the target.